# Using AutoMapper for JOIN operation without Foreign key

Tags: linq, join, automapper

I have db TABLES:

```
Company(CompanyId, Name, UserId, CompanyType, Uid)
User(UserId, FirstName, LastName, SocialNumber)
```

And in application MODEL:

```
CompanyModel(CompanyId, Name, CompanyType, Uid, UserName)
```

Since *CompanyModel* and *Company* have many same type and name Fields I tend to use AutoMapper to avoid writing explicitly all of those fields.
But here I now need to get UserName.
If *UserId* had FK I would have been able to do it like this:

```
var mapper = Mapper.CreateMap<Company,CompanyModel>();
mapper.ForMember(
    d => d.UserName, 
    s => s.MapFrom(a => a.User.FirstName + " " + a.User.LastName));
var q = companyQuery.Project().To<CompanyModel>();
```

But *UserId* in *Company* table don't not have Foreign key relationship constrain with *User* and I can't create it.
So at the moment I am doing it with join:

```
var r =
from c in companyQuery
join u in userQuery on c.UserId equals u.UserId
select new CompanyModel
{
     CompanyId = c.CompanyId,
     Name = c.Name,
     CompenyType = c.CompanyType,
     Uid = c.Uid,
     UserName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
};
```

I would like to know if there is any way to do this with AutoMapper, and how? so I can skip naming all fields (this is just sample, there are much more fields).

Is anyone familiar with this ?

Comment: I got one explanation here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/automapper-users/C5vde3Yvp5M